# Cannot create new AWS Java Web Project in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have gone through the [steps given by Amazon](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSToolkitEclipse/latest/GettingStartedGuide/tke_setup.html) to install Eclipse and the AWS Toolkit for Eclipse. I installed the Java EE version of Eclipse that they suggest.

When I attempt to create a new AWS Java Web Project it fails with an error: "Dynamic Web Module 2.5 requires Java 1.5 or newer." I am using Java 8 (I checked this in Eclipse), and I have been unable to locate the source of the problem.